# problemas con el SDK de android studio

Tags: android-studio, sdk

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola buenas estoy necesitando ayuda en android-studio. Particularmente es con el SDK. ya tuve instalada la versión anterior de android-studio  y nunca tuve problemas para iniciar el emulador. Ahora me pide instalar el emulator hipervisor driver.
lo instalo y me arroja este error StartService con error 4294.
desinstale el programa y lo volví a instalar y sigue el mismo error al iniciar el emulador.